# LeafletJS, allow only one marker within a defined area

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, leaflet

I am developing an application that allows users to place markers on a leaflet map(it is an image instead of a geographical map) which are stored in a MySQL database.

The query: I want to restrict the placement of markers in such a way that only one marker is allowed for a certain area on the map. This is basically to avoid overlapping of markers.

How do i write the restrict function to define the area that takes only one marker within it ?

Comment: Placement of markers depend on the latitude and longitude provided. Do you mean `marker-clusterer` ? https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: Too broad. Do you want to apply the limitation in the client side when editing, in the server side when saving the edits, in the server side when data is requested, or in the client side when displaying the results??

Comment: @IvanSanchez preferably on the client side as I want only one marker added in a predefined area, so it would be better to have a check at the client side before the marker data goes to the server. A popup or a custom message can be displayed if a new click violates the condition.

Comment: An how do these areas look like? How does the client fetch a copy of them?

Comment: @IvanSanchez a clarification first, its not a geographical map, but an image(like a floor plan). The area is predefined by me. something like one marker per 100 sq/ft. the query is basically how to calculate the area(how to convert physical square feet into pixels on map, so i can create a custom array of the pixels within the area i want to define) and then compare it with the lat,lng(or that lat,lng point converted to an actual pixel) values of the new onclick event and then allow or deny adding the marker to db.

Comment: OK, so I'm gonna guess you want to use a rectangular grid (you should add this info to your original question, adding an image if possible, to clarify). Do you have a function that takes in a lat-lng and returns a grid cell? Something similar? Do the cells ever change?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks, will update the question, I am new here. The cell size is practically the size of the marker icon, which in this case is [25x25]px. so If I can define a cell of [25x25]px With the marker as center, I can then avoid overlapping. So can you please shed some light on how to proceed with this in mind ?

Comment: But the size of a 25px cell changes with zoom level...

Comment: @ivansanchez there should be a way to define an x that equates the 25px to the current zoom level, right ? If not please guide.

Comment: No. Scale in a spherical mercator projection is not constant.

Comment: It seems that you don't have any clear requirements. Please think hard about what you need, and what's the problem you're having. Here in SO we don't like to feel like doing design or requirements gathering tasks for other people.

Comment: @ivansanchez ok, I am sorry for being vague. I will get into the details and come up with a specific issue. Thanks.